# how to interact with specific forms (that are dynamically created) when there are multiple forms on the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a page that contains multiple forms that are dynamically created based on the users input, so a page can have just one form or many. The forms consist of two sets of radio buttons, the second set is disabled by default and is enabled based on the users choice in the first set of radio buttons.

This part works absolutely fine, when the user makes the appropriate selection from the first question the second question is made available. However, this applies to all the forms at the same time, so when the selection is made on form 1 all the other forms react based on form 1's input.

Each form has a dynamic class using the id from the database so how do I tell jquery which form the user is interacting with? So that when the user makes a choice on one form it only affects the second set of questions on that particular form?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mealSection').prop('disabled', true).css('opacity', '.2');

  $('.attendRadio').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "Attending") {
      $(".mealSection").prop('disabled', false).css('opacity', '1');
    } else {

      $(".mealSection .mealRadio").prop('checked', false);
      $('.mealSection').prop('disabled', true).css('opacity', '.2');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="processRSVP.php" method="post" class="rsvpForm[<? echo $r['GuestID']; ?>]">
  <fieldset class="attendSection">
    <input type="hidden" value="<? echo $r['GuestID']; ?>" name="id">
    <div class="attendOption">
      <input class="attendRadio" type="radio" name="attend[<? echo $r['GuestID']; ?>]" value="Attending">Hell Yeah!
    </div>
    <div class="attendOption">
      <input class="attendRadio" type="radio" name="attend[<? echo $r['GuestID']; ?>]" value="Not Attending">...Nah
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="mealSection">
    <div class="mealOption">
      <input class="mealRadio" type="radio" name="starter[<? echo $r['GuestID']; ?>]" value="Option 1">Option 1
    </div>
    <div class="mealOption">
      <input class="mealRadio" type="radio" name="starter[<? echo $r['GuestID']; ?>]" value="Option 2">Option 2
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="rsvpButtonContainer">
    <input type="submit" name="<? echo $r['GuestID']; ?>" value="confirm">
  </div>
</form>
<form action="processRSVP.php" method="post" class="rsvpForm[<? echo $r['GuestID']; ?>]">
  <fieldset class="attendSection">
    <input type="hidden" value="<? echo $r['GuestID']; ?>" name="id">
    <div class="attendOption">
      <input class="attendRadio" type="radio" name="attend[<? echo $r['GuestID']; ?>]" value="Attending">Hell Yeah!
    </div>
    <div class="attendOption">
      <input class="attendRadio" type="radio" name="attend[<? echo $r['GuestID']; ?>]" value="Not Attending">...Nah
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="mealSection">
    <div class="mealOption">
      <input class="mealRadio" type="radio" name="starter[<? echo $r['GuestID']; ?>]" value="Option 1">Option 1
    </div>
    <div class="mealOption">
      <input class="mealRadio" type="radio" name="starter[<? echo $r['GuestID']; ?>]" value="Option 2">Option 2
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="rsvpButtonContainer">
    <input type="submit" name="<? echo $r['GuestID']; ?>" value="confirm">
  </div>
</form>
```

I get that at the moment all that my jquery is doing is waiting for a change of state on the first radio buttons and that it doesn't care which form the change comes from. I've tried using focus but my understanding is that only works with the form elements not the actual form itself? I've tried looping through each form but that doesn't seem to work either, although I have a feeling that I'm just going about it all wrong.

Any help at all is greatly appreciated, just a nudge in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Use additional data field in your radio buttons, and then in the change function, read those additional data to determine which form is it.

Comment: you want to check after form submit in or in js?

Comment: @OmerMuhammad - in js, i want the form to enable the second question when the user clicks "hell yeah" but only for that form not all of the forms like in the code snippet example I have provided.

Comment: thanks @MdMonjurUlHasan I shall try that when I get home.

Comment: upon the selection of first radio button, try to get the id of particular form. ad then generate form2 under the selected form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your callback takes a event argument you can access the element the user is interacting with with `event.target`<sup>1</sup> and you can access the containing form using the `parents`<sup>2</sup> jQuery method and from there you can call `find`<sup>3</sup> on the form element to specifically access only elements inside of it:

```
$('.attendRadio').change(function(event) {
  var formEl = $(event.target).parents('form');

  if ($(this).val() === "Attending") {
    formEl.find(".mealSection").prop('disabled', false).css('opacity', '1');
  } else {
    formEl.find(".mealSection .mealRadio").prop('checked', false);
    formEl.find('.mealSection').prop('disabled', true).css('opacity', '.2');
  }
});
```

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target
[2] https://api.jquery.com/parents/
[3] https://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: the third link is exactly the information that I've been looking for, thanks this is perfect!